# Permanently delete SQL server database - anti recovery

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security, recovery

I rent a server from a server provider. And one day I'm no longer rent it. I have some important database on the server need to wipe out so no one can see it. Is that safe to just right click on the database and select Delete? Is there any tools or method that able to recover a deleted database?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways the database could be recovered:

- Database Backups. You need to make sure you're removing all database backups as well by shifting them onto on-premises storage and securely deleting on the rented server.
- Server Backups. Your provider is possibly providing server-level backups. These would have older copies of the databases on them, so would need to be securely deleted.
- Data Recovery on the underlying storage. The deleted files on physical storage may still be recoverable, so you need to ensure that the storage is being securely deleted. This usually involves zeroing the disks multiple times to securely delete the data.

You should check with your provider regarding guarantees for secure data deletion when you exit the service to see if that meets your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because the underlying storage database located in 'C' drive which same as OS installed location , and I cannot physically access to the server I renting to zeroing disk many times. About the server provider, they won't guarantee it for me and I need to do it myself.